# Smart Contract Deployment

Tags: web3js, ether, smart-contract-wallets

Is it possible for a smart contract to send out eth in the background?

if so please how would the smart contract look like and the web3 html if possible

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `transfer` function like this;

```
function SenEth(address payable beneficiary) pubic{
    uint balance = address(this).balance;//This will send all the balance inside the contract
    beneficiary.transfer(balance);
}
```

You can also send a fixed amount instead of the entire balance. The web3 part would be a simple call to the contract function.

Comment: Thank you but still not clear, cause what i want is send eth from a wallet to another all will run in background. i have tried a few code but still pop up to confirm instead of just send out. can you please explain how to go about this? and also if i already deploy a smart contract on remix and then reload the page do i need to redeploy it?

Comment: Can you explain the logic of the page using this logic? To understand a little better

Comment: okay, im making a gaming dapp which when you connect your wallet an amount of ether will be remove and send to the contract. and if you win the contract will send it back along side your winnings without having to click confirm again

Comment: The thing is someone will have to pay for that gas of the returning of the winners price, so it will always ask the user to confirm